# What is the efficient way to copy vectors of one data type into a vector of struct of the same data type?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, memory-alignment

I have a a vector of struct with 3 member variables **(vec3)pos (vec3)norm (vec2)texCoord** and I have have 3 other independent vectors of **(vec3)x (vec3)y (vec2)z** respectively, I want to copy/combine 
the data from the independent vectors into the vector of the struct data type that I have mentioned above so that the variables will be aligned in accordance to the variables in the struct. 
I can archieve this by iterating through each member of the vectors and assign the variables, however Iam looking for a faster more efficient approach to copy the whole range of a vector to the other vector with one or two function calls is there such a way to achieve this?

pseudo code:

```
struct foo
{
vec3 pos;
vec3 norm;
vec2 texCoord;
}

vector<foo> attributes;

vector<vec3> x;
vector<vec3> y;
vector<vec2> z;

copy(x, attributes, offsetof(foo::pos), stride);
copy(y, attributes, offsetof(foo::norm), stride);
copy(z, attributes, offsetof(foo::texCoord), stride);
```

Comment: What you seen to need is a tree-input variant of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Which is pretty easy to implement yourself.

Comment: @user207421 iam looking for an efficient way without the need to iterate through each member variable

Comment: @Some programmer dude what about the memory alignment of each variable within the struct? Do i have to worry about when using ```std::transform``` ?

Comment: Given that you data is non-adjacent, I doubt, there is something as efficient as `memcpy` for this case.

Comment: @Albjenow ```memcpy``` does not consider the memory alignment of the struct it simply copies the whole range right?

Comment: Exactly, you can only copy continuous memory with it.

Comment: I don't see a way to avoid having to iterate over all 3 input arrays. You can make it syntactically simpler (following eg. @Someprogrammerdude's suggestion), but not algorithmically. You do have a choice whether you want to process the 3 input arrays sequentially (and thus go over the output array 3 times), or interleaved (and thus go over the output array once). The latter might involve less instructions, but might or might not be worse on the cache behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, if we would know the byte alignment, we could maybe do some low level dirty stuff.

But if we stick to C++ on a higher level, we do not have so much possibilities.

Here some examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


using vec3 = int;
using vec2 = int;

struct foo
{
vec3 pos;
vec3 norm;
vec2 texCoord;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<foo> attributes{};

    std::vector<vec3> x{1,2,3};
    std::vector<vec3> y{4,5,6};
    std::vector<vec2> z{7,8,9};

    // How many elements do we need to copy
    size_t elementsToCopy {std::min({x.size(), y.size(), z.size()})};


    // Solution 1 one. Straight forward. Emplace back and creation of temporary is slow
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elementsToCopy; ++i)
        attributes.emplace_back(foo {x[i],y[i],z[i]});


    // Solution 2. Slight improvement. Set initial size of target vector. Then copy in simple loop. Creation of temporary is slow
    attributes.resize(elementsToCopy);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elementsToCopy; ++i)
        attributes[i] = std::move(foo ({x[i],y[i],z[i]}));

    // Wrapping in algorithm. But no real improvement. More a less just obfuscation
    std::for_each(attributes.begin(), attributes.end(), [i=0U, &x,&y,&z](foo &f) mutable { return std::move(foo ({x[i],y[i],z[i]}));++i;} );

    for (const auto a : attributes)   
        std::cout << a.pos << " " << a.norm << " " << a.texCoord << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I think, existing algorithms will not help here very much. We could write a lambda or function. But this will make the code more nice, but not faster.

I think that there is also a flaw with the 3 vectors x,y,z. They may be of any size.

Maybe adding member functions for struct foo would be a safer solution. Some add function or similar.

But unfortunately I have no ideal solution.

Comment: if it is possible I would like to see the low level code just for the sake of other people (including me) that might be interested into seeing it, the byte alignment should be straight forward the struct members are **12+12+8** bytes respectively.